# Recover a bitcoin wallet in Hive

Tags: backup, hive

I've recently reformatted my Mac, and reinstalled Hive. I have a back up to Dropbox option enabled in Hive, and my old bitcoin wallet file is there. But I cannot find any way to recover my old bitcoin wallet to my new installation. Being able to back up but not recover doesn't make much sense to me right now, can anyone help me with this process?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dropbox stores all previous versions of hive files for at least a month. You can open the backup folder in Finder and find the bitcoinkit.wallet file. Right-click this and select "View Previous Versions". This should open your Dropbox account and show you the previous versions of the wallet file.

Check the backup at ~/Library/Application Support if the backup files are there. If not, copy the backup files to that folder. Then start Hive, and it should detect the existing wallet and send you straight to the main window without going through the welcome wizard (note: you'll have to wait a bit for it to resynchronize with the Bitcoin network again).

Hope this works!